# How do I make the GeoServer GeoPackage Output extension produce valid text fields?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geopackage

We have the GeoPackage Output extension on our GeoServer. However, a WFS GetFeature request with outputformat=gpkg returns a geopackage with invalid text fields.

An attempt to read the geopackage using FME gives these warnings:
"Field format 'VARCHAR(255)' not supported."
"GPKG: unrecognized user_version=0x00000000 (0)"

Both FME and QGIS read the geopackage, but drop the invalid fields.

I can't find any suggestions on how to configure the extension to give a valid output. The correct data type in geopackages would be TEXT, but how can I achieve that?

The version of the extension matches the GeoServer version 2.22.2

Edit: I included all FME warnings here. Also other incompatible datatypes are found, but at least the integer fields are not dropped. I just noticed that for some reason FME mentions geometry columns here, but the actual geometry column is none of these and was read correctly.

OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'VARCHAR(255)' not supported
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: geometry column 'id' of type 'VARCHAR(255)' ignored
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'INT4' not supported. Interpreted as INT
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'INT4' not supported. Interpreted as INT
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'VARCHAR(255)' not supported
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: geometry column 'muokkauspv' of type 'VARCHAR(255)'  ignored
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'VARCHAR(255)' not supported
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: geometry column 'link_id' of type 'VARCHAR(255)' ignored
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'INT4' not supported. Interpreted as INT
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'TIMESTAMP' not supported
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: geometry column 'hakupv' of type 'TIMESTAMP' ignored
OGCGEOPACKAGE reader: Field format 'INT4' not supported. Interpreted as INT

The layer source is a PostGIS table.
DescribeFeatureType output:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="dr_nopeusrajoitusType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="alku_m" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="loppu_m" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="vaik_suunt" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="arvo" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="muokkauspv" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="link_id" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="kuntakoodi" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="hakupv" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="id_pk" nillable="false" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: does the geopackage open in other programs (e.g. QGis)?

Comment: You write that FME gives warnings. Warnings should not prevent reading the data. Do you actually get errors instead?

Comment: I edited my question: Both FME and QGIS read the geopackage, but drop the invalid fields. FME gives warnings, not errors.

Comment: what is the source of the GeoServer layer? can you add the describeFeature output for that layer too.

Comment: @IanTurton sure, added it

Comment: You say QGis "drops the invalid fields"  - which fields does QGis consider invalid?

Comment: @IanTurton the same which FME ignores: id, muokkauspv, link_id, hakupv